# Can the quick time event in Chapter 06 of Fahrenheit/Indigo Prophecy be successfully completed?

Tags: indigo-prophecy

In chapter 06 of Fahrenheit/Indigo Prophecy there is a series of QTEs where Lucas is attacked by strange creatures in his office. At the end of the sequence at an elevator the QTE becomes very fast and pretty much impossible to complete.

Is this QTE sequence programmed to be unwinnable and fails regardless of input or could it theoretically be completed and the game reacts to this?